# Rethrowing from caught 

Tags: c++, exception

If I throw an exception:

```
throw Cat("Minoo");
```

Then I catch and rethrow with ... at some lower level in the call stack:

```
catch(...)
{
  throw;
}
```

Then at some other lower level in the call stack I try to catch with:

```
catch(const Cat& c)
{
  //Will it enter here, and if so will c be valid data?
}
catch(...)
{
}
```

Comment: With questions like this. Why not just try. It would take you 30 seconds to find the answer.

Comment: @Martin York: Because if the answer to my question was actually, not valid data, then there would be no way to verify that.  Because sometimes it would be valid and sometimes not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. This is addressed in [the very next question](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9) of the section of the C++ FAQ that I linked you to on your previous question.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I did not see it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, it will catch it and should be valid. This is actually fairly easy to test (at least you'll know if it works on your compiler). When in doubt just try it out ;).